# Flex SWF application on facebook post does not communicate to backend for Chrome and Explorer

Tags: facebook, apache-flex, flash

I have developed a simple Flex application that allows to a Facebook user to record audio. This application is published in facebook posts as SWF video (using "source" parameter on facebook post). My SWF communicates to a CMS backend to receive some parameters and to upload the audio file once it is recorded locally via flash player.
The application works OK for Firefox and it communicates to CMS without problems, but it does not communicate using Explorer or Chrome browsers. Any suggestion?

Another important point: the application works OK accessing it directly on Explorer or Chrome ( without loading it via Facebook post), so the problem is just when it is accessed via Facebook post.

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/feed-gaming/
I'm reasonably sure you can't make calls back to the server, you need to configure the SWF via URL parameters

Comment: I see your point. But the thing is that this is happening just with two browsers. It works ok using Firefox. Regarding your response , could you point me the way to pass configuration parameters for SWF via URL? (I am using flashvars parameters for my swf, but don't know how to pass it configuration params such as "AllowScriptAccess")

Comment: I don't think you can turn on script access for embedded files in news feed posts